# Image.path Error when Cancelling Image Picker from Gallery/Camera

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-image

I have a feature wherein I edit my Image using Gallery or Camera options.
I don't know how to handle when the user pressed the back button while trying to pick from gallery to switch to camera.

The debugger then shows the Error that "Image.path was called on Null";

**SOLUTION**

For those who will experience this error. Tapping Back while on gallery or camera.
Just use `if (imageFile != null)` to avoid app crashing.

Comment: Please show us your script

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your Scaffold with WillPopScope

```
return  WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () => _exitApp(context),
        child:  Scaffold(
            appBar:  AppBar(
              title:  Text("Navigation Demo"),
              backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
            ),
```

and ask user Do you want to exit this application or current page ?

```
Future<bool> _exitApp(BuildContext context) {
  return showDialog(
        context: context,
        child: new AlertDialog(
          title: new Text('Do you want to exit this application?'),
          content: new Text('We hate to see you leave...'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
              child: new Text('No'),
            ),
            new FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
              child: new Text('Yes'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ) ??
      false;
}
```

detail reference https://codingwithjoe.com/flutter-navigation-how-to-prevent-navigation/